# After Update of Springfox from 2.9.2 to 2.10.4 error "Unable to infer base url. ..."

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I just updated the Springfox dependency in my Spring Boot application (version 2.3.1.RELEASE) from 2.9.2 to 2.10.4.

```
<spring-boot.version>2.3.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
<swagger.version>2.10.4</swagger.version>
```

Due to class changes in the `springfox.documentation.*` packages, I had to change the annotation in my configuration class from

```
@EnableSwagger2
```

to

```
@EnableSwagger2WebMvc
```

Also the Predicate import changed from Google Guave to `java.util.function`. My current Configuration class looks like this

```
package de.rewe.zlip.config;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.RequestHandler;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ParameterBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.schema.ModelRef;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.service.Parameter;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2WebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2WebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).globalOperationParameters(globalOperationParameters())
                                                      .select()
                                                      .apis(sourceScannedForRestApis())
                                                      .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                                                      .build()
                                                      .apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo())
                                                      .genericModelSubstitutes(Optional.class);
    }

    private List<Parameter> globalOperationParameters() {
        List<Parameter> operationParameters = new LinkedList<>();
        Parameter authorizationParameter = new ParameterBuilder().name("Authorization")
                                                                 .description("Your Bearer token ")
                                                                 .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                                                                 .parameterType("header")
                                                                 .build();
        operationParameters.add(authorizationParameter);
        return operationParameters;
    }

    private Predicate<RequestHandler> sourceScannedForRestApis() {
        return RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("de.my.package");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiEndPointsInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("TEST SERVER REST API")
                                   .description("REST API provided for the TEST web application")
                                   .contact(contactInfo())
                                   .version("v1.0")
                                   .build();
    }

    private Contact contactInfo() {
        return new Contact("Test Team", "https://", "test@test.com");
    }

}
```

When I open http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html now, I get the following message:

> Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet
> registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is
> the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if
> the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the
> base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location
> manually:

Needless to say, the same configuration (except of the 2 changes mentioned above) worked with 2.9.2. Most of the tips in earlier questions are adding

```
@EnableSwagger2
```

but since this annotation has changed in 2.10.X to either `@EnableSwagger2Mvc` or `@EnableSwagger2Flux` this won't help.

Answer (score 3):

From [springfox issue tracker](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3336):

> Oh please dont use 2.10... it was an intermediate step so that people who were on 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT can continue using a released version if needed.

I suggest reverting back to 2.9.2 for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below.

1. Add this dependency to your pom.xml

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
>   <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
>   <version>${your.spring.fox.version}</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Add this line to either your main class or your swagger config class

> ```
> @Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
> ```

Comment: Not related to the issue.